# C# Dictionary ContainsKey/TryGetValue not working

Tags: c#, dictionary, long-integer, containskey, trygetvalue

I've looked around for a while and seen plenty of references to modifying `GetHashCode()` and things when playing with `ContainsKey()` and `TryGetValue()` - but all those issues and examples have all been with some obscure user-specific key.

I have a basic `Dictionary<long, object>`. When trying either `ContainsKey()` or `TryGetValue()`, it doesn't always get a hit (when it should) and moves on to attempting to populate the missing entry (as it technically should if that were the case).

You guessed it: it then complains about the existing key because, well, it exists.

So why is it having problems matching a basic `long` key and how do you make it behave?

Edit: Code. I have tried several things. In their most basic form:

```
public void Add(long id)
    {
        if (AreaDataDict.ContainsKey(id)) return;

        AreaData ad = new AreaData(id);
        ad.Load();
        AreaDataDict.Add(id, ad);
    }
```

Also:

```
public void Add(long id)
{
    AreaData areaData;
    if (AreaDataDict.TryGetValue(id, out areaData)) return;

    AreaData ad = new AreaData(id);
    ad.Load();
    AreaDataDict.Add(id, ad);
}
```

Edit 2: No key changes are happening. Other than adding if the value is not found, data is only read from this.

Comment: Could you give as an example code when it really fails? It's just guessing unless we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure we'll find this is a bug in your code. Unfortunately, you haven't provided that code, so we can't help you - please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We can *easily* provide examples of it working, but that won't surprise anyone.

Comment: Example of your code would be very useful. We can try guessing..

Comment: Is this a multithreaded scenario, by chance?

Comment: Can you post some of your code? Are you not changing the key in another thread or something?

Comment: Krenom, can you answer if this is a multithreaded situation against a shared dictionary, keeping in mind if your environment is ASP.NET or another similar multiple concurrent user/thread environment, you could have race conditions.

Comment: Ugh, yes, it is. Thank you, apparently no one thought about that...
I've just switched it to a `ConcurrentDictionary<long, object>` and all my problems seem to have magically disappeared.

Comment: We are completely sure no key changes are happening, because you use `long` for your key type (`TKey`). And `long` is an _immutable_ type, fortunately. Also, we know that `long` has a great `GetHashCode()` implementation, so this cannot be the problem (it often is in other `Dictionary<,>` questions). Of course if you create the dictionary while supplying a bad home-made equality comparer for `long` (an `IEqualityComparer<long>`), it can malfunction, but I guess that is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `ConcurrentDictionary` was the answer, thankfully inspired by user454076.